# SQL Server: Tag the records based on position of a character

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data like this

```
id     DATA
---   ------------------------------------
2      A2015      745745098     1 1236789
3      B2015      9823459869233          
4      B2015      9823459869233          
5      C00000002      0000000000000003300
6      A2015      745745098     B 234579A
7      B2015      9823459849234          
8      B2015      9823459909235          
9      B2015      9823459909235          
10     B2015      9823459849234          
11     B2015      9823459909235          
12     C00000005      0000000000000000000
13     A2015      745745098     6 1234568
14     B2015      9823459889231          
15     B2015      9823459861             
16     B2015      9823459889231          
17     B2015      9823459862             
18     B2015      9823459819230          
19     B2015               3             
20     C00000006      0000000000001810220
21     A2015      745745098     D 123467A
22     B2015      9823459879239          
23     B2015      9823459879239          
24     B2015      9823459879239          
25     B2015      9823459879239          
26     C00000004      0000000000000008400
27     A2015      745745098     A 1234567
28     B2015      9823459869235          
29     B2015      9823459869233          
30     B2015      9823459869234          
31     B2015      9823459869236          
32     C00000004      0000000000000040500
```

Expected result

```
id    TAG       DATA
---   ----    ---------------------------------------
2      1      A2015      745745098     1 1236789
3      1      B2015      9823459869233          
4      1      B2015      9823459869233          
5      1      C00000002      0000000000000003300
6      B      A2015      745745098     B 234579A
7      B      B2015      9823459849234          
8      B      B2015      9823459909235          
9      B      B2015      9823459909235          
10     B      B2015      9823459849234          
11     B      B2015      9823459909235          
12     B      C00000005      0000000000000000000
13     6      A2015      745745098     6 1234568
14     6      B2015      9823459889231          
15     6      B2015      9823459861             
16     6      B2015      9823459889231          
17     6      B2015      9823459862             
18     6      B2015      9823459819230          
19     6      B2015               3             
20     6      C00000006      0000000000001810220
21     D      A2015      745745098     D 123467A
22     D      B2015      9823459879239          
23     D      B2015      9823459879239          
24     D      B2015      9823459879239          
25     D      B2015      9823459879239          
26     D      C00000004      0000000000000008400
27     A      A2015      745745098     A 1234567
28     A      B2015      9823459869235          
29     A      B2015      9823459869233          
30     A      B2015      9823459869234          
31     A      B2015      9823459869236          
32     A      C00000004      0000000000000040500
```

On rows with id 2, 6, 13, 21, 27 have reocrds that starts with letter 'A' and it has one distinct character at position 26. For example, on row with id 2 there is character '1'. On row with id 6 there is a character 'B' at position 26 and so on. I want to identify this character and print it as a tag for all the rows that follows it till a next record is found that starts with 'A'. The same should be repeated with all the reocords that starts with A. I am ok to use a function for this.

Comment: Please share the approach/solution you have tried. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky.  It looks like the tag is in a fixed position.  So, you can do:

```
select t.*, t2.tag
from t outer apply
     (select substring(t2.data, 26, 1) as tag
      from t t2
      where t2.data like 'A%' and t2.id <= t.id
      order by t2.id desc
     ) t2;
```

Comment: **(1)** `from t2` --> `from t` **(2)** `) t;` --> `) t2;`

Comment: **(3)** `15`-->`26`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . That 26 is a killer.  I was counting from the wrong position (obviously).  Who would put a fixed position string in a field called `data`?  Alas.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!! It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.Tag
      ,A.Data
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select Top 1 ID,Tag=Substring(Data,26,1) 
               From  @YourTable 
               Where substring(Data,25,3) like ' _ '
                 and ID<=A.ID
               Order By ID Desc
               ) B
```

Returns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,substring(data,26,1) as tag from tablename
where data like 'A%'
```

Answer (score 0):

- starting with SQL Server 2012

---

```
select      id
           ,min (case when data like 'A%' then substring(data,26,1) end) over (partition by a_seq)  as tag
           ,data          

from       (select      id
                       ,data
                       ,count   (case when data like 'A%' then 1 end) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as a_seq

            from        t
            ) t

order by    id
;
```